# Make WebBrowser click a button on a webpage with a specific class ONCE in VB.net

Tags: html, vb.net, click, webbrowser-control, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to make the webbrowser click on a specific button within a webpage:

The html code for the button is something like `<a class="btn btn-large play">` and the code I have so far to click this button is:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("btn btn-large play") Then
Element.InvokeMember("click")
End If
```

This works, but it makes the Webbrowser click the button again and again. Any idea how I can only make it do so twice?

Comment: This loop iterates through all the elements in the given Document. By assuming that there is only one element containing the OuterHtml text "btn btn-large play", it would be clicked just once, every time this loop is used. From your code, I don't know when/how many times this loop is used but, presumably, it is inside a method which is called more than once.

Answer (score 2):

maybe simply like this? :)

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("btn btn-large play") Then
Element.InvokeMember("click")
Element.InvokeMember("click")
return
End If
```

Comment: If now the button is being clicked "again and again", with your code it would be clicked 2*(again and again) :) It does not seem to be a solution for what the OP is complaining about.

Comment: @varocarbas shouldn't return exit the loop after the second click?

Comment: As commented above, the problem does not seem to be provoked by the loop itself, but by "where" (method) this loop is being executed which is seems to be called more than once. If you break the loop or exit the method it wouldn't avoid this method to be called again. The OP should explain under which conditions this loop is being called.

Comment: @varocarbas or maybe there are just a couple of buttons containing "btn btn-large play"?

Comment: This is also possible (a couple or one hundred; it is outertext...), but if the OP does not describe the conditions better, there is no way to help him accurately.

Answer (score 1):

And Why do you not try to detect the kind of element in the webbrowser:

***Code snippet originally of @ElektroStudios, I'm just a lammer who pastes code without attribution.***

```
Dim Document As HtmlDocument

Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Document = sender.Document
    AddHandler document.Click, New HtmlElementEventHandler(AddressOf Document_Click)

End Sub

Private Sub Document_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As HtmlElementEventArgs)

    Select Case Document.ActiveElement.TagName.ToLower
        Case "button" : MsgBox("You've clicked a button")
        Case "input" : MsgBox("You've clicked a input")
        Case "a" : MsgBox("You've clicked a link")
        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub
```

Later you can replace `MsgBox("You've clicked a link")` by some function or event or sub and do what do you want.. :D

Comment: Supplying code snippets without author attribution (Me) you are violating SO terms.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public count as integer=0

Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object,ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

If count<2 then

For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("btn btn-large play") Then
Element.InvokeMember("click")
End If

count=count+1
end if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be sufficient to exit the `FOR` loop when you've already clicked once the item, so try this:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")

    If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("btn btn-large play") Then

        Element.InvokeMember("click")
        Exit For

    End If

Next Element
```