# How do i click this button in VB?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

This is the button element:

```
<input type="image" class="btnClaim" src="http://cdn1.swagbucks.com/content/results/images/btnClaimPrize.png" onclick="sb_vd.capSubmit();">
```

I've tried this code:

```
 Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
                        For Each element As HtmlElement In allelements
                            If element.GetAttribute("class") = "btnClaim" Then
                                element.InvokeMember("click")
```

but it does not click the button. How do I programmatically click this button?

Comment: You don't click the button in your VB.NET code. You click it in JavaScript or if wanting to call the method from your VB.NET code, you just call the VB.NET function

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - this is a winforms app using a webbrowser control. The OP wants to invoke a click in the webbrowser control dom. I have added the appropriate tags to the question

Comment: is it possible to click the button within my vb application or not?

Comment: Check this one, they use OuterHtml instead of GetAttribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463854/make-webbrowser-click-a-button-on-a-webpage-with-a-specific-class-once-in-vb-net or this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8a40ca8e-f983-446a-9ca1-26f91e57b31f/vbnet-how-to-click-a-javascript-button-webbrowser?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Yes that link helped perfectly. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with javascript

```
  window.onload=function()
  {
   img_click();
  }
  function img_click()
  {
    //do the code
  }
```